# How to create a keyboard shortcut for Chrome's "Search Google For..." from context menu

Tags: google-chrome, hotkeys

In Google Chrome, I often use the feature where you can select text, right click on the selection and click "Search Google for '...'" it opens a new tab with a search for whatever was selected.  Great feature, but I would love to be able to assign a keyboard shortcut to do the same thing once I have selected some text.  I already have AutoHotkey installed and have some basic knowledge of the program if that would help.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using AutoHotkey:

```
^+c::
{
Send, ^c
Sleep 50
Run, http://www.google.com/search?q=%clipboard%
Return
}
```

By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it copies highlighted text to the clipboard, then opens a new tab/window with a Google search of whatever was in the clipboard.  It also works outside of the browser, which is nice; any highlighted text system-wide can be searched for with one hotkey.